# Unable to check my Australia ETA status

Tags: visas, australia, eta

I try to check my Australia ETA status, but the message "There has been no application for an ETA through this site with the data and reference number you supplied." appeared. But when I try to submit new application, the system said I already have the visa (with correct details as in my email confirmation that send by ETA earlier for my 1st application entry).  What is actually happen?

Comment: Same thing happened to me for applying for my second year visa. It was a little nerve racking, but I just waited it out and eventually it came through. If you're worried, just contact them, otherwise, hope for the best like i did ;)

Answer (score 3):

Don't know, but sounds a bit weird, so best to get in touch with Immigration and/or your nearest Australian embassy.  [Contact information here](http://www.immi.gov.au/contacts/visa-enquiries/eta.htm#a).